# react-ace editor causes content security policy error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, reactjs, meteor, ace-editor

I am having a wierd issue with react-ace. I am using the editor with Meteor and mobx. Full issue here: https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/186

(1) In essence, if I use an Ace Editor instance with mode as 'toml', it works fine. If I use the same instance with 'html', the browser throws a CSP issue. I have tested this in both Chrome and Firefox.

(2) Using 'toml', there are no errors.

(3) Using 'html', with only the two lines changed, i.e. the mode and its source, this throws a CSP error shown in the image below.

[Console with html selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHTnH.png)

(4) Any pointers would be appreciated. I spent a bunch of time trying to debug with limited success. I have tried to make the CSP less restrictive, but the env is a single page meteor app. I am confused at this point.

(5) I just upgraded my react, but i don't think that is the issue. Tested on both (a) Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 unknown (64-bit) [Ubuntu] and (b) FF 52.0.2 (64 bit) [Ubuntu] - the first two warnings are due to this, so can be ignored.

(6) Super simply code:

```
<AceEditor
name="ace"
mode="html" // this is the only line i am changing...
theme="chrome"
width="100%"
fontSize={18}
value={this.props.siteTemplateStore.aceTmpValue}
onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
editorProps={{$blockScrolling: true}}
/>
```

Note, the error is: Refused to create a worker from 'blob:...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data:". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

ace tries to create a webworker for html syntax checking which is blocked by csp due to the rule allowing self and data. To fix the issue add blob to the whitelist